# Slick: can't load image in update loop

Tags: java, lwjgl

As you can see from the code below, I am trying to import "someimage.png". This is so in the render loop, I have the right image. I put the second line of code. Is this possible? If not what is an alternative. Thanks in advance.

```
public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) {
    //if statement
    Image x = new Image("someimage.png");
}
public void render() {
    //draw image x
}
```

There is an "unhanded exception type SlickException".

Comment: @Moonbeam slick is an extension of the LWJGL (light-weight java game library) specialized for 2D games

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the variable "x" is local to the update() function.  If your render() function tries to call "x", maybe it's a different variable?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this Slick tutorial here](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/wiki/doku.php?id=01_-_a_basic_slick_game), it shows a basic game setup with image loading. Basically, you want the Images to be member variables of your game class, their values set in the init method, and the render method to draw the pictures. Although this setup will work fine for very simple games, you are probably better off using objects to represent the different things in your game. I hope this helps.